# spring 3 beginner jdbc implementation

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am an absolute beginner to spring web mvc and specially spring 3. I have no clue as to how should I do the JDBC coding. I have seen spring 2.5 step by step guide..but what I want to do is, I have a controller and view. I want to use that view to display data stored in a table in the db.. simple! Could anyone, please write a code snippet for me to understand it simply? I am using mysql database.

Here is my controller:

```
package com.src.springdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloC
 */
public class HelloC extends HttpServlet implements Controller{
     protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         logger.info("Returning hello view");

            return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL the problem is i am novice to spring and dont know how to integrate jdbc intro spring 3. all the tutorials are very difficult to understand and are of spring 2.5

Comment: But there *are* examples, and tutorials-plus a lot of the 2.5 stuff is still applicable. I'd consider reading the reference docs and asking more-specific questions when you have them.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am looking for more specific spring web mvc jdbc thing

Comment: The web part is irrelevant. It's not clear to me what issues you're having, or why the docs and normal tutorials/blogs/etc don't address them-can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You should use JDBCTemplate, it simplifies the JDBC coding considerably. The documentation is here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Usually you'd write a service class that wires a JdbcTemplate, and wire the service into the controller. Also, the code for JDBC hasn't changed much from 2.5.6 to 3.0.5 so you should be able to follow any 2.5.6 tutorial without much (if any) changes.

Also, the spring 3 way is probably to use annotations (@Controller, @Autowired, @Service, etc.) on POJO beans rather than using the Controller base class.

EDIT:
There are examples on spring's main doc page for jdbc: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/jdbc.html

Comment: @Kevin.. mate.. i have seen this... but dont know how to start and where to start from! What files do I need to create and all... a simple and short demo to `select * from mytable_name`

Answer (score 0):

Spring mvc step by step is a useful guide. I am also new in spring. As a beginner [vaannila.com](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-tutorial/spring-tutorial.html) can be useful for you. Here you will get some clue for JDBC coding that can be solve your problem.